# Mail Composer Address Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I found email composer sample code from iphone OS Ref Library. Here is a code-

Code:

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"];
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil];
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"];
```

My question is how to take user's input? Here all email address are predefined in code. so what are the IDs of to, CC, Bcc, subject and body fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. To Give a Email address as user input only.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *msgTitle = @"Sample Title";

    [picker setSubject:msgTitle];

NSArray *toRecipients =[[NSArray alloc] init];

NSArray *ccRecipients =[[NSArray alloc] init];

NSArray *bccRecipients =[[NSArray alloc] init];

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  

[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    NSString *sum = @"The Email Body string is here";

NSString *emailBody;

emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sum];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];


  -(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
  {
     NSString *recipients = @"mailto:?cc=,&subject=@";

     NSString *body = @"&body=";

     NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];

    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];

  }
```

Best of luck.

Comment: -(void)launchMailAppOnDevice

is it required to modify
if yes then please tell me how i put all arrays in this method

Comment: @Arun Sharma. I think thats method is not reqired. If u want more details, see my updated answer. It may help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setToRecipients:arr];
    [controller setCcRecipients:arr2];
    [controller setBccRecipients:arr3];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO];
```