# Mail Composer Problem with app ondevice method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this code for mail

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *msgTitle = @"Sample Title";

```
[picker setSubject:msgTitle];
```

NSArray *toRecipients =[[NSArray alloc] init];

NSArray *ccRecipients =[[NSArray alloc] init];

NSArray *bccRecipients =[[NSArray alloc] init];

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];

[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

```
NSString *sum = @"The Email Body string is here";
```

NSString *emailBody;

emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sum];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];

it works,

i want to know,is it required to modify

-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
 NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello from California!";
 NSString *body = @"&body=It is raining in sunny California!";

NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
 email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}

if yes then
how i modify in this method.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If email address is given statically and displayed in To address.

You can use this code,

```
   MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {    
    [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AAA@BBB.com",nil]];

    [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];

}

 [mail release];
```

And

[see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948591/mail-composer-address-problem/2949567#2949567)

Best of luck.