# How to prepare a mail interface like mail in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to prepare the mail interface for show mail and compose same as mail in iphone in my application.

Please suggest me any idea for how I prepare the layout for show mail and compose mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to actually let the user send an e-mail, instantiate a `MFMailComposeViewController` and present it as a modal view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but MFMailComposeViewController is not helpful for me because when I use it,it sends mail through email account which is configured on my device. I want to implement own method for it.

Comment: In that case, a look at the [Three20 framework](http://github.com/facebook/three20) might help you as it contains a class that implements much of Apple's functionality (`TTMessageController`).

Comment: I m trying to add Three20 framework in my project. After adding Three20 framework, There is one error when I run my project :-
CANNOT FIND #import "Three20/Three20.h".

How I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use MFMailComposeViewController to send an Email in your application.

see [My Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956210/mail-composer-problem-with-app-ondevice-method/2956448#2956448)

[Another Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948591/mail-composer-address-problem/2949567#2949567)

It will help you.