# problem at opening compose mail

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i need id i have to open support@ensisinfo.com on button click. i need simple compose mail with to address support@ensisinfo.com how can i done this pls post some code thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to check if `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` is YES. If so, then you *can* send e-mail, otherwise, no accounts are setup.

Next you'll want to create an `MFMailComposeViewController`, and conform to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` delegate. From there, on your `MFMailComposeViewController`, you will want to look at the `-setSubject:`, `-setMessageBody:isHTML:` and the `-setToRecipients:` methods, and finally on your "parent" view controller, `-presentModalViewController:animated:` to bring your compose view up for the user to send the mail, and release your `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code into your button action,

```
      MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
      [[mail navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];// Change the navigation bar color
       mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

       if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

               [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"support@ensisinfo.com",nil]];

               [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
    }

    [mail release];
```

For more clarification, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948591/mail-composer-address-problem/2949567#2949567)

Best Of Luck.